# Getting list of all tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching

How can I get list of all the tags on Stack Overflow?

The number of tags is quite large and I want to see all of them in a place/page rather than moving page by page. I need this, so I can subscribe to tags relevant for me in one go.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the paginated list - there are 36 tags per page... and (at present) 941 pages of tags. That makes ~33876 tags in total.

If you tried to get the entire list of these tags all in one page, the page would timeout before it even loaded.

Perhaps there's another way to accomplish what you're after?

Comment: yes.. am seeking some other way.Getting a list in any format so that i can pick relevant ones and add them as my favorite using normal tag addition method. This will suffice my purpose.

Comment: So - how would you define "relevant" WRT tags you want to see? If there's a way to define that precisely, then another way might be possible.

Comment: By relevant i mean tags related to operating system , its subcomponents , tags related to virtualization , xen , c language etc. I see many tags related to very specific areas of these technologies. Currently i go for serach/add method or i subscribe if i see such tag in some que.

Comment: Hmmm. so perhaps a way to relate tags to one another - so you could then have say a "show me tags related to tag-X" page?

Comment: I wouldn't be opposed to a way to search tags like `%stack%` or `[stack*]`

Comment: If you put a tag into the searchbox (eg [stack]) and submit... then in the right-hand-side menu is a list of "related tags"

Comment: Yes, it's not wildcard-compatible. That sounds like an interesting idea.

Answer (score 1):

[Just query the `Tags` table on the Stack Exchange Data Explorer.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/81619/all-tags)

Comment: Yeah, but isn't the Data Explorer data behind by some weeks?